# Django Rest Framework JWT- got 401 error when token is a part of Header

Tags: authorization, django-rest-framework, jwt, restangular

Working with Django REST Framework JWT at server side and AngularJs and Restangular at client side, when I set username and password in header:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Authorization': 'Basic ' +$base64.encode('username:password')});
```

it works correctly.

But when I set token as part of  header :

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({Authorization:'Bearer '+ StorageService.get("access_token")});
```

I get **401 (UNAUTHORIZED)**  error.

My viewset:

```
class BookViewSet(DefaultsMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

Setting:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication'

),
```

}

Request Headers (part)

```
Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Authorization:Bearer"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InRqYW5hdGkxMUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE0NDc2NzYxNDcsInVzZXJfaWQiOjEwOSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJwcDEiLCJvcmlnX2lhdCI6MTQ0NzY3MzE0N30.ImkGmK9_TNU5lCvcGzgNi-1XS_Q4c_AxHSnJOcjn6O8"
...
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I assume this is the JWT token type. In that case you should use the following format in your header:

```
Authorization: JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InRqYW5hdGkxMUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE0NDc2NzYxNDcsInVzZXJfaWQiOjEwOSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJwcDEiLCJvcmlnX2lhdCI6MTQ0NzY3MzE0N30.ImkGmK9_TNU5lCvcGzgNi-1XS_Q4c_AxHSnJOcjn6O8
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the token was not being sent.